# SharePoint 2013 create custom approval workflow with comments

Tags: workflow

I am having a relatively direct Task to deal with and need some help.

I need to build a Workflow (2013 or 2010 or a mix of both is fine) That does roughly the following:

1. Be started when a document is requested to be approved or manually
2. Do some changes to the item, if needed (Set a boolean Field to true)
3. Start a Task for Users in a Multi Lookup Field/People Picker in the ListItems properties, this Task needs to be commented
4. Start a Task for Users in another People Picker, this Task needs to be commented as well
5. Publish the ListItem, once again Setting some values (A Text Field "Reviewer" and a Text Field "Approver", a Text Field "Version" and a Text Field "VersionDate")

If in the Steps 3 and 4 the Document was not Approved, the Editor of the Document needs to recieve a Mail with all comments
If in Step 3 the Document was Approved, Users from Step 4 will need to be able to see the Comments

I am at a complete loss on how to implement this behaviour. I do think about mixing it up with a Farm Solution at some points because I am not as familiar with SharePoint Designer as I am with C#.